# SQL Server: Set Date Range to be Between --> 10 years ago from today's date and 10/11/2017

Tags: sql-server, date, dynamic, range, between

I want to select a date range based on my "DTIN" column.  I want my date range to be between two date values.

I want my DTIN dates to be between 10 years ago from **today's date** and a pre-set date of October 11th 2017.

Below is the line of code I tried but SQL Server tells me the AND statement is off.

```
WHERE [DTIN] BETWEEN (DATEADD(Year, -10, GETDATE()) AND (CONVERT(datetime, '2017-10-11'))
```

I am aware that my 10 year's ago from today's date is also off in the code above.

Comment: To fix your problem with `AND` you need another `)` after `GETDATE())` so that it is `GETDATE()))`

Comment: ah you are right!  thank you :)

Comment: Note: It might help, in future, to remove unnecessary parentheses (e.g. the ones encasing `DATEADD...` and `CONVERT...`). It makes the coder slightly harder to read with no real benefit (and, of course, sometimes leads to errors like this).

Comment: Convert is more of display formatting, Cast is the way to go.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu what do you mean by `Convert is more of display formatting, Cast is the way to go` ?

Comment: if you want compare date/time just use Cast(datefield as date) rather than convert(varchar(10),datefield,103) as convert is for formatting.

Comment: There is no difference between these options (except the syntax) `convert(date,'2017-10-11')` or `cast('2017-10-11' as date)` they are exact functional equivalents. In older versions of sql server it was necessary to use a third parameter (style) in the convert function to output/display date/time information, but that also requires conversion to char/varchar. Due to this history many will associate convert() with just that role, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: It isn't necessary to use either cast or convert for a date literal in the always safe YYYYMMDD format, plus: `between` isn't accurate for date ranges especially if your data is datetime or datetime2. A far more reliable way to form a date range is to use `WHERE [DTIN] >= DATEADD(Year, -10, GETDATE()) AND [DTIN] <  '20171011'` or `WHERE [DTIN] >= DATEADD(Year, -10, GETDATE()) AND [DTIN] <  '20171012'` if yo do want to include all data for 2017-10-11

Comment: "SQL Server tells me the AND statement is off" - it would be more helpful, rather than providing your interpretation of what SQL Server is saying, to include the *actual error message*. (Even if it's not in English, including the error message *number* will let people work out which message is being displayed)

Comment: got it ... will do next time